# Are structs necessary in binary search trees

Tags: c++, struct, binary-tree, binary-search

I've looked at some code for BSTs and I can see that each node is a struct.  Is this necessary?

Comment: Structs arent necessary. You can use classes instead. In C++, classes default to private members, everything in the class definition prior to your first public or protected declaration will be private. Structures, by default have members as public.

Comment: What do you mean by necessary?

Comment: Structures are not necessary.  Any data type can be used.  BSTs need to have pointers to nodes and the nodes need to have content (or they can be pointers to data).  For example, you could have an array of void pointers:  `void * tree_array[200][3];` where the last dimension is for *left, data,* and *right* pointers.  Do you have something against `struct`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int flat_tree[ 1000 ][ 3 ];
    // for each tree node, value is stored in element [id][0]
                        // id of left_child stored in element [id][1]
                        // id of right_child stored in element [id][2]
```

…

I'm not gonna go any further with this.

Generally speaking, `struct`s/`class`es are used for any kind of linked data structure. Also generally, any feature of the type system may be defeated or ignored and you can do everything (heap allocation, etc) in one array of `int`s in very painful fashion.

Comment: Best answer so far: at the same time, it shows two answers. Theoretically no, practically yes.

Comment: A second dimension may make this easier, where the index values can be 0 for left, 1 for data, and 2 for right.

Comment: @Thomas: relatively speaking ;v)

Answer (score 4):

No, it could be a class.  It can't be a primitive, because it needs to store a value and also point to children.

Well, I should say that you could also represent your BST as an array, where the left and right children of the node at position `i` are in positions `2 * i + 1` and `2 * i + 2`, respectively.  But then you would have to worry about resizing, and you would need a special value to represent null, and delete operations become pretty complicated.  I don't recommend this approach as anything other than an academic exercise.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your answer. I think you meant **3** * i + 2, though.

Comment: 3 seems better... This confusion is a good argument why one should use structs.

Comment: This is basically the technique behind Robert W. Floyd's Treesort 3 sorting algorithm (Algorithm 245 from ACM).  It was published about two years after Quicksort.  It had O(N log N) performance, but was presented as a nonrecursive algorithm.

See http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=365103&CFID=77012854&CFTOKEN=98159140 for the gory details, in Algol.  (You'll need an ACM Digital Library subscription to download the PDF.  It is WELL worth the money IMHO!  Unpaid plug.)

Comment: Oh, I see now. That's more like an inside-out heap. For a black-box algorithm it might be analogous to a tree, but something requiring rebuilding rather than relinking can't properly be called a tree.

Comment: Of course it can be called a tree.  A tree doesn't have any particular implementation - it is just a directed, acyclic graph.

Answer (score 4):

Its not mandatory.
But since the data a node contains along with the two links together form a  logical entity they are usually put together in a struct. So that it becomes easier to code functions that take a node as an argument or return a node.

Answer (score 1):

No, not strictly speaking.  In the FORTRAN days, people used parallel arrays, or two-dimensional arrays.

Tony Hoare's section of "Structured Programming" by Dahl, Dijkstra, and Hoare, talked about data structuring and record types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simpler than parallel arrays if your payload admits a sentinal value: you can use a implicit tree (that is, not bother with links at all).

```
payload_type a[tree_size];
```

Just a long flat array containing only payload values, with position in the array coding for link structure:

- `a[0]` is root
- `a[1]` is root->left
- `a[2]` is root->right
- `a[3]` is root->left->left
- `a[4]` is root->left->right
- ...

For the node at position i, go to 2*i+1 for left and 2*i+2 for right

You initialize it to all sentinal values, and start adding things...